# VSTS API Commit Diffs

Tags: git, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way through the VSTS Rest API (WIQL) to see the actual changes that occurred to files in a commit? I was hoping for something like git's diff from command line but the VSTS documentation for the Diff API only describes showing which files changed, not what was changed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/diffs/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1

Thx

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/20?

Answer (score 0):

If you open a commit in VSTS and check the API's calls you can see that:
[image]

This Rest API give this response (the actually changes on the commit):
[image]

The problem is... this API not dedicated to showing the changes, to get the changes we need to put some values on the body request, you can find the body in the "Headers" tab under "request Payload":
[image]

This body is very long (press on "view source" to see the whole body), you can "play" with it and try to get the commit changes.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/phun-ky/97bacd9f57e14acdaabecbdd03f13c5c) you can find another body, you can also try it.